# Server doesn't display a right content in browsers after wordpress installed as a tutorial

Tags: wordpress

At the beginning of the new year, I buy a domain: [danielpan.me](http://danielpan.me). After creating a **droplet** in [digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/), I deployed **wordpress** on my remote server. The tutorial I followed is [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-14-04). But something I didn't understand happened. After removing the file of **/var/www/html/index.html**, my server displayed like this:

[image: Wrong isplaying after removing index.html]

You know, this is not a right result. It should display something like this:

[image: Right display after removing index.html]

This confused me a lot. I don't know how to do next after that much googling. Even so I don't want a solution about redirections.

Comment: Does your server support PHP ?

Comment: @Raptor, I tried to copy **/var/www/html/wordpress/index.php** into **/var/www/html/index.php**. But the browser show nothing.

Comment: Not making sense to Copy `index.php` around. You probably need to forward your visitors to `/wordpress` folder... or do you intend to use WordPress at domain root ?

Comment: Of course not, @Raptor, I just wanted to show the root Url in browsers, but now, it doesn't work

Comment: I intend that the content of the address bar remains `danielpan.me` while the second picture will display.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new file on root folder names `.htaccess` and input following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /wordpress [L]
```

This code will redirect your root page `danielpan.me` to `danielpan.me/wordpress` where the wordpress codes are located and you'll be up and running there.

Comment: @BikesVaibhav, I had executed `a2enmod rewrite` and `service apache2 restart` in command line, doesn't it work? And these: `touch /var/www/html/.htaccess`, `chown :www-data /var/www/html/.htaccess`, `chmod 664 /var/www/html/.htaccess`, `chmod 644 /var/www/html/.htaccess`

Comment: Till now you've just enabled the rewrite engine. Now you've to tell it what to redirect and to where. The .htaccess command will do exactly that.

Comment: @BikesVaibhav, new file `.htaccess` on root folder? `/var/www/html/.htaccess` has already existed, don't both conflict with each other?

Comment: Then just update the redirect rule in that itself. Make these lines at the top.
Also, since .htaccess doesn't normally exposes anything personal, you can also share content here so that I can update that for you.

Comment: The content of `/var/www/html/.htaccess` is here:_# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress_

Comment: when I input `danielpan.me` in address bar and Enter, the result of the second picture is displayed, meanwhile, the content of the address bar is changed into `danielpan.me/wordpress`, but actually i want it to remain `danielpan.me`,  Could this be achieved?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73055/discussion-between-bikas-vaibhav-and-silentknight).

Answer (score 1):

A server is generally configured to display some default files is none is declared. So if you navigate to `http://example.com`, it will first try to display the `index.html` file. If that is not available, it tries to display `index.php` and so forth. This may not be the real order, but I think it also depends on the server configuration. So if none of the files in that list is found, it may display what are you seeing, which is called `directory listing`. You can turn it off using an `.htaccess` file with the content: `Options -Indexes`.

Comment: @lulianOnofrei, after `vi /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf` executed, `DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml index.htm` showed, Isn't it the right order of the file list?

Comment: Since none of the index file exists in the root directory, Directory Listing is enabled & no `.htaccess` to serve 404 request, your screen will look like the one showing. The Apache is probably badly misconfigured.

Comment: @SilentKnight, AFAIK, there's no "right" order. That is the default order, and you may tweak it to your needs. But generally, you wouldn't have to.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect your visitors to http://danielpan.me/wordpress, the path where you installed WordPress, you can make a simple HTML script to do so (save it as index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Redirecting...</title>
<script>
window.location = 'http://danielpan.me/wordpress';
</script>
</head>
<body>
Redirecting...
</body>
</html>
```

The above solution is client-side redirecting. If the visitor disabled JavaScript (99% they won't, though), the redirection won't work.

Hence, there are an alternative for you, using PHP (save it as index.php):

```
<?php
header('Location: ./wordpress/');
exit;
?>
```

Server-side redirection is often more reliable.

The last solution is to use `.htaccess`, which other answer has been mentioned. I don't gonna repeat that again.

Hope these help.

Comment: Yeah, all solutions above you referred are about redirection. And yes, now It redirects indeed. But, this is not what i want.  What I wanna see is: when I input `danielpan.me` in address bar and Enter, the result of the second picture will be displayed, meanwhile, the content of the address bar doesn't change and remains `danielpan.me`, but not `danielpan.me/wordpress`, Could this be achieved? @Raptor

Comment: Then you should move your WordPress files into your domain root instead.

Comment: OMG! it's not a good idea, i think. Isn't there another solution?

Comment: You should do so. Redirection is no good to SEO. Moving files via FTP takes only seconds. Is there other concern you have?

Comment: I'm afraid that if doing so, I would not be capable of operating successfully any longer on the back-end of WordPress[link(http://danielpan.me/wordpress/wp-admin/index.php)] where I deployed the whole website

Comment: You can login at http://danielpan.me/wp-admin/ instead. Suggest to re-install though